# jquery datepicker prevent native click in onSelect

Tags: jquery, events, datepicker, click, onselect

I'm in struggle trying to prevent native click inside jquery datepicker.onSelect event

Example below is not working, click still is being triggered:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 

if (myCondition) {
   return false; 
 }}
```

Another trick would be calling event.preventDefault/ inside onSelect, if event object has been available.

Any known solutions ?

Comment: preventDefault is the right solution.. What exactly are you trying to find?

Comment: I have no idea how to access event object inside onSelect

Comment: By prevent "click" you mean prevent populating the selected date to get populated to the input field that Datepicker is attached to?

Comment: Not exactly, by default Datepicker "dates" are being highlighted onClick, I just want adllow/prevent highlighting on my custom condition inside Datepicker.onSelect 

Sure, I could bind some "independent" onclick handler "outside Datepicker namespace", but it would be some ugly solution - an unnecessary dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can achieve this via CSS instead of binding to events?

Answer (score 1):

What if you used the beforeShow event ? as referenced here http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShow

This way, you could really *prevent* the datepicker from being displayed.

Regards,

Max