# Add custom classname to jquery calendar cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery calendar. I am trying to insert a new class name to each cell of calendar. It gets added but it is getting removed as and when the calendar is clicked.

Basically it refreshes the calendar on every click so newly added class is getting removed on refresh.

How do I retain the class name?

here is my code

```
$(function() {
  $('#custom-date-format').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "y-m-d"
  });
  $('.ui-state-default').addClass("calendar_bg");
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/543w1pg3/6/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback functions of Datepicker Widget

```
    $('#DatePicker').datepicker({
       //The calendar is recreated OnSelect for inline calendar
        onSelect: function (date, dp) {
           updateDatePickerCells();
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(month, year, dp) {
            updateDatePickerCells();
        },
        beforeShow: function(elem, dp) { //This is for non-inline datepicker
            updateDatePickerCells();
        }
    });

    updateDatePickerCells();

    function updateDatePickerCells(dp) {
        /* Wait until current callstack is finished so the datepicker
           is fully rendered before attempting to modify contents */
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.ui-datepicker td > *').each(function (idx, elem) {
                $(this).addClass("calendar_bg");
            });
        }, 0);
    }
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bjm4bf56/1/)

For multiDatesPicker()

```
$(function() {
    $('#from-input').multiDatesPicker({
        beforeShow: function(elem, dp) {
            updateDatePickerCells();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you suppose to override the existing `.ut-state-default` background-color instead of going for adding new one?

```
.ui-state-default{background: #ffeb3b !important}
```

Comment: I am using class for other purpose not only for the bg color so it would be great to know the possibility of adding class name.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known tricky jQuery UI calendar issue, see this question [jQuery ui - datepicker prevent refresh onSelect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056287/jquery-ui-datepicker-prevent-refresh-onselect)

Anyway, the fix is to add `inst.inline = false;` on select, like this

```
$('#custom-date-format').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "y-m-d",    
    onSelect: function(date, inst){
        inst.inline = false;
        $('.ui-state-default').addClass("calendar_bg");
    }    
});
```

See a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/543w1pg3/7/), note however, that it throws an error in multidatespicker.js. There seems to be an issue with this plugin.

Comment: But this removes the class when u click on next month.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the existing class name and override its default styling.

Add this style **`.ui-widget-content a.ui-state-default { background: #ffeb3b }`**

Here is the same [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/543w1pg3/10/)