# Calendar event with datePicker - stop Refresh

Tags: jquery, events, datepicker, calendar

I need to develop a calendar with event associate on some day. I make this with datePicker and look my calendar :

[image]

I've created some events ( 3 in total ) and the color on days 1, 2 and 3 are day with event !; when I click on a day with an event, it displays the event info into a specific div.

All is ok, that work, BUT when I click on a day with element, my div with color for event disappear.

Check my code :

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var events = [<?php $nb = 0;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'evenement',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $nb++;
             $date = get_field('date');
             $date_info = explode("/",$date);
             $year = $date_info[2];
             $month = $date_info[0];
              $day = $date_info[1];
              /** HACK TO GET GOOD DAY / MONTH FORMAT todo: optimise it */
               if($day == "01"): $day = '1'; endif;
               if($day == "02"): $day = '2'; endif;
               if($day == "03"): $day = '3'; endif;
               if($day == "04"): $day = '4'; endif;
               if($day == "05"): $day = '5'; endif;
               if($day == "06"): $day = '6'; endif;
               if($day == "07"): $day = '7'; endif;
               if($day == "08"): $day = '8';endif;
               if($day == "09"): $day = '9';  endif;
               if($month == "01"): $month = '1'; endif;
               if($month == "02"): $month = '2'; endif;
               if($month == "03"): $month = '3'; endif;
               if($month == "04"): $month = '4'; endif;
               if($month == "05"): $month = '5'; endif;
               if($month == "06"): $month = '6'; endif;
               if($month == "07"): $month = '7'; endif;
               if($month == "08"): $month = '8';endif;
               if($month == "09"): $month = '9';  endif;
               //if($day == "0".$x): $day = $x; endif;?>{
            Title: "<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>",
            Date: new Date("<?php echo get_field('date'); ?>"),
            Lieu: "<?php echo get_field('ville'); ?>",
            Extrait: "<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>",
            Type: "<?php echo get_field('type'); ?>",
            Year: "<?php echo $year; ?>",
            Month: "<?php echo $month; ?>",
            Day: "<?php echo $day; ?>"
            }<?php //if(count($nb) == $nb): ?>,<?php //endif; ?><?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>];

        $("#cal_content").datepicker({
            dayNamesMin: [ "Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam" ],
            monthNames: [ "Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre" ],
            nextText: "Suivant",
            prevText: "Précédent",
            //dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var result = [true, '', null];
                var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
                    return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
                });

                if (matching.length) {
                    result = [true, 'highlight', null];
                }
                return result;


            },
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                var date,
                    selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
                    i = 0,
                    event = null;

                // Determine if the user clicked an event:
                while (i < events.length && !event) {
                    date = events[i].Date;

                    if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                        //console.log('clicked');
                        event = events[i];
                    }else{
                        //console.log('no clicked');
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (event) {
                    // If the event is defined, perform some action here; show a tooltip, navigate to a URL, etc.
                    //alert(event.Title);
                    $('#cal_event_content').html(
                        '<div class="event type_'+event.Type+'">'
                            +'<span class="title">'+event.Title+'</span>'
                            +'<span class="date">'+event.Day+'/'+event.Month+'/'+event.Year+'</span>'
                            +'<span class="lieu">'+event.Lieu+'</span>'
                            +'<span class="content">'+event.Extrait+'</span>'
                            //+'day : '+event.Day
                        +'</div>'
                    );
                }
            }
        });

        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default").each(function () {
            var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year").first().html();
            var nb;
            var month = $(this).parent().attr("data-month");
            var real_month = +month +1; // need this hack to get good month id ( datepicker put 9 for october per exemple )
            for (nb = 0; nb < events.length; ++nb) {
                if ( ($(this).parent().attr("data-year") == events[nb].Year) && ( real_month == events[nb].Month )  && $(this).html() == events[nb].Day) {
                    var type = events[nb].Type;
                    $(this).after('<div class="puce_color '+type+'"></div>');
                }
            }
        });

    });
})( jQuery );
```

When I click on a date, my `puce_color` disappear..

Can someone help me please ?

I would love to add multiple event per day too.. but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It will be nice if you can make an example of your code into a demo site like codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok i will test this ! thanks

Comment: You can test there : http://codepen.io/gfardoux/pen/gwKPpN thanks !

Comment: Well so I have a part solved ... don't remove your elements on select but they are still removed when you change month, will work on that

Comment: Sorry i'm french i don't understand very well your answer, what i have to do ? thanks

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRkGpZ/

Comment: WAOUWWWWWW thanks so much man !!!! you saved my life :) can i abuse just a little bit and ask you how can i setting up more than 1 event per day ?

Comment: Right now I don't have time .... give me an hour or two

Comment: you are the best, i can't stop to say thanks

Comment: hi @DaniP ! Did you have some moment to help me with multiple event per day man ? please.. thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is every time you select a date the calendar is "refreshed". This answer will be divided in three parts with a final demo code on Codepen:

## Stop Redraw on SelectDate

With this we ensure the appended elements will remains visible on the actual calendar view, on your Select funtion set `inst-inline` to false:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        inst.inline = false;
```

<sup>[Related Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6233850/2887133)</sup>

---

## Redraw on change Month

You also lost your appended event indicators when the month change since the events are just attached on load you can change this to run like a function everytime you change the month:

```
function drawEvents(fnyear, fnmonth, fnobj) {
  $('#' + fnobj).find(".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default").each(function() {
    var nb;
    for (nb = 0; nb < events.length; ++nb) {
      if ((fnyear == events[nb].Year) && (fnmonth == events[nb].Month) && $(this).html() == events[nb].Day) {
        var type = events[nb].Type;
        $(this).after('<div class="puce_color ' + type + '"></div>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Then on load run the function with the actual calendar date:

```
var startdate = $('#cal_content').datepicker('getDate'),
    startmonth = startdate.getMonth() + 1,              
    startyear =  startdate.getFullYear();
drawEvents(startyear,startmonth,"cal_content");
```

And on ChangeMonth execute the function:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, widget) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    drawEvents(year, month, widget.id)
  })
}
```

<sup>**Note::** The `setTimeout` function ensures the change on the actual month --- [Related](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5354)</sup>

---

## [CodepenDemo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEKEob/)

---

## Multiple Events on a Day

Check for 21/10/2016

## [CodepenDemo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpjJgw)

Comment: thanks a lot for this ! i will try as soon as possible

Comment: hi DaniP, can i make more than 1 event / day with this solution please ? i dont think so :/

Comment: np mate glad to help U ... just accept and upvote here to close the question cicle

Comment: ok i'll try ! i'm newbie on this website, but i'll use everytimes ahah man, i got some work like this in my job, maybe you'll be interest to work with me on some project ? not for free ;)

Comment: i can't upvote.. not yet ;) later no prob, thanks again man, really.. you saved my life too much time

Comment: jejeje glad to help U @1way I really enjoy to help, if later require something my info is into my profile here  .. have a nice day

Comment: i sent you an email on your gmail address :)

Comment: Man, are you there ?